# How to capture app version to console via grep and regex?

Tags: regex, macos, grep, zsh

My regex is weak. I am ashamed, but it's true.

I can log the entire line containing a Mac app's (Xcode's) version to the console via a command like this:

```
defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist | grep 'CFBundleShortVersionString = "'
```

That displays a line like this:

```
    CFBundleShortVersionString = "14.2";
```

How would I add a regex to the grep command to capture the "14.2" bit? I know I need to use something like `([0-9]+.[0.9]+) (capture 1 or more digits, a period, and one or more digits) but can't get it to work.

Comment: You have some typos, also period and `+` need escape. `grep '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+'` seems to work.

Comment: or `[0-9\.]\+` I think

Comment: I thought the "[0-9]+" bit meant "match 1 or more instances of "0-9" (a number)

Comment: My goal is to have `14.2` displayed to the console (I want to capture the `14.2` bit from the line and log that to the console.)

Comment: @svlasov : What's the point in escaping the `+`? There is no literal + in the output which the OP would want to match.

Comment: Your regex is a bit too coarse, since you want to match a **literal** dot. It should be `[0-9]+[.][0-9]+`. Also you would need the `-o` option, because otherwise _grep_ outputs the whole line.

Comment: @user1934428: grep manual: _In basic regular expressions the meta-characters `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`, `(`, and `)` lose  their  special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions `\?`, `\+`, `\{`, `\|`, `\(`, and `\)`._

Comment: @svlasov : It depends. For GNU grep for instance: Even if we don't specify `-E`, grep understands `+` as special. You could argue that the OP forgot to provide the `-E` option, but perhaps he is using GNU grep and did not notice the omission. In my answer, I used `-E` in my answer, because on MacOS (unless you install the GNU untilities), they are really using basic regexp only. Have a look at my answer, and let me know if you can improve something.

Comment: The `defaults` [man page](https://ss64.com/osx/defaults.html) says it will accept a key. Does this return what you need ?:
`defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleShortVersionString`

Comment: Sonofagun, that works. @Gairfowl, can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: (I would still like to understand how to do it with RegEx for my education, but your approach is much simpler.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pipe that line into

```
.... | grep -o -E '[0-9]+[.][0-9]+'
```

Comment: I tried variations of that. It doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @DuncanC : This error description is not useful. In this case, post the whole command you tried, together with the output you received. To verify that my approach is correct, try on the command line `echo abc 24.567 | grep -o -E '[0-9]+[.][0-9]+'`. This outputs 24.567. I bet you have some typo in your attempt.

Comment: Your variant does not match on the 'CFBundleShortVersionString' key, so it returns every n.n number sequence in the plist. It returns 6.0 /n 14.2 /n 13.0 /n 13.0 /n 12.5 /n 1.0

Comment: @DuncancC : That's why I wrote "Just pipe **that line** into....". Of course you need first extract the line, and then you feed it into the command I posted. You have two `grep`: One for finding the line, and one for finding the desired string inside the line.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I missed that bit. A multi-step grep would certainly work. I was hoping to figure out how to output a capture group from RegEx as the result of the grep command.

Comment: For other people reading this, the full command, using 2 separate grep commands, looks like this: `defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist | grep 'CFBundleShortVersionString = "' | grep -o -E '[0-9]+[.][0-9]+'`. That or @Gairfowl 's answer using a key in the `defaults read` command gives the desired result.

Comment: @DuncanC : You can do this in one go, by using for instance `awk`. However, I suggested my `grep` solution since it simply adds a missing piece to what you already have. Also, getting the number part out of the selected line is a bit more tricky with awk than with grep.

Answer (score 1):

The `defaults` command [will accept](https://ss64.com/osx/defaults.html) a key, and will return a value for that key, so this should report the value you're looking for:

```bash
defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleShortVersionString
```

In some quick tests, it appears the `defaults` command wants an absolute path (starts with `/`) when specifying a plist file instead of a `com.apple.something` domain.

Also, the man page has this note:

> WARNING: The defaults command will be changed in an upcoming major
> release to only operate on preferences domains. General plist
> manipulation utilities will be folded into a different command-line
> program.

The note has reportedly been there since at least 2017, so that may not happen anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```bash
defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist | \
    sed -n 's/.*CFBundleShortVersionString = "\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/6JalDJ).

*Details*:

- `n` - suppresses the default line output
- `.*CFBundleShortVersionString = "\([^"]*\).*` - matches the whole line that contains `CFBundleShortVersionString = "`, and then captures all zero or more chars other than `"` right after it into Group 1
- `\1` - replaces the whole line with the Group 1 value
- `p` - outputs the result of the successful replacement only.

Answer (score -1):

```
(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)\";$
```

It will match `1.2` or `1.2.4`